# Write blog in drupal - the best way to insert text to content type

Tags: drupal-7

I want to know what is the best and common way to write SDK blog in drupal.

1. Write the blog directly to new content type in drupal.
2. Write and design the blogs in word document (or something similar), and later, with process (module that I will write) load all the docs into content type.
3. Other.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to enter your blog entries directly into Drupal -- like you said into whatever content type you're using for your blogs!  If that's an option you (or whoever the blog author(s) may be) are willing to do, better get used to it at the beginning.

There are several problems you may run into if you're choosing to create your content outside of Drupal and pasting it in after the fact.  At the minimum I can now think of the following two:

- Folks can run into formatting issues when Word styles are copied and pasted into the Drupal editor of your choice (even though there are 'Paste from Word' options for some of the editors).  Especially if there are multiple authors and some adhere to proper copying and pasting, while others don't, you can end up with posts that have different font sizes, font styles, etc and that can make the site look less professional.  I'd suggest always creating the content within the Drupal editor, regardless of the scenario.  However, that is particularly true when there are multiple authors creating content outside the Drupal editor (for example in Word) and pasting it in after the fact.  With multiple folks, training and adherence to best practices can become more of an issue.  To see formatting problems, give it a test yourself: create some fancy, styled content in Word (not just plain paragraphs or it won't really be that interesting) and paste it into CKEditor or whatever else you're using.  Then inspect the html code that results using the 'Source' button on the editor.  Don't use 'Paste from Word' option that usually helps.
- If you have images in your posts, you won't be able to just copy and paste them into the Drupal editor from Word... you'd still have to upload the image and insert it into the post the Drupal way

So, rather than creating the content once, copying and pasting it and potentially having to do a ton of clean-up after the fact, just get used to creating it in Drupal!

Then -- as your blog grows and you potentially add to it (additional fields, additional features), you'll be able to more fully take advantage of your Drupal environment if your workflow doesn't include an outside program like Word in it!!

Comment: If i like the authors to edit their posts in drupal with CKEditor, their font might look different anyway... Do you think that SDK docs can look professional like in MSDN? Maybe i better create my won editor? Or i can do better with exist editors with less develop time? BTW - thanks for your detailed answer!